# Simulate "deleted Inode reference" error

Tags: linux, simulation, inode

Sorry if this question is asked already; but I could not find any such post.

I am currently working on an issue on inode reported by a customer.

**Issue:**
In customer system, we see the following error every time he reboots:
`EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 3855`
After googling, I found about "fsck" and have made changes in the bootup code to fix this.

**Question:**
Before I give my build, I need to confirm if my fix is really working fine or not. So my question is that: *how can I simulate this error so that I can* *try in our dev systems and verify if the fix is working or not?*.

**Details:**
`$> uname -a
Linux VCFC4CN8513000U 2.6.34.6 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 29 01:56:25 PDT 2016 ppc GNU/Linux

$> mount
...
/dev/sda1 on /mnt type ext4 (rw,noatime)`
sda1 is the partition in which I want to delete some inode references.
Any pointers to simulate this inode deletion scenario?
I am thinking `dd` command should give me some clues; but I just cant get it right. I will update here if I get to recreate this scenario using this.

Thanks!